# PHP 7 C++ extension. The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, c++, windows, zend-framework

I wrote an extension with C++ for php on windows. I build multiple different versions:

- php 5: with a MSVC11 compiler, linked with php5ts.lib, thread safe and it works fine
- php 7: with a MSVC14 compiler, linked with php7ts.lib, thread safe, but it didn't work

The php 7 version gives me

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/openserver/ospanel/modules/php/PHP-7.0/ext/module_php_7.0.21_TS.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.0.21 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2017 13:31:19) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

I tried to change extension folder, rename file, nothing helps. Library was built without any error. I double checked that it exists.

P.s: I know there is a difference between php5 and php7 api, i have #ifdef for this, so it's not a problem. Also we have successful build of this module with php7 on linux.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved an issue. It was a mistake in build script. `php5ts.lib` and `php7ts.lib` was included at same time. I deleted `php5ts.lib` from linker and now it works as expected.